# calculate more than one column using for loop based multiple specific conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
 B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num   Patient_count
    1     0.2       S1        1          1
    2     0.3       S1        2          1
    3     0.8       S1        3          1
    4     0.3       S1        3          2
    5     0.6       S1        4          1
    6     0.8       S1        5          1
    7     0.9       S1        5          2
    8     0.4       S1        5          3
    9     0.6       S1        5          4
    12    0.9       S2        1          1
    13    0.5       S2        1          2
    14    0.3       S2        2          1
    15    0.7       S2        3          1
    20    0.7       S2        4          1
    16    0.6       S2        5          1
    17    0.8       S2        5          2
    19    0.3       S2        5          3
```

where

No_Show = Probability of no show

Assume that

p = [0.2, 0.4] and Duration for each slot = 30 (minutes)

p = threshold probability

From the above I would like calculate below data frame

Step1

sort the dataframe based on Session, slot_number and Patient_count

```
df = df.sort_values(['Session', 'slot_num', 'Patient_count'], ascending=False)
```

step 2 Calculate the cut off by using below conditions

if patient_count = 1 Divide No_show by threshold probability if patient_count = 1

```
Example for B_ID = 3, Patient_count = 1, cut_off = 0.8/0.2 = 4
```

else if patient_count = 2 multiply previously 1 No_Show with current No_show and divide with threshold)

```
Example for B_ID = 4, Patient_count = 2, cut_off = (0.3*0.8)/0.2 = 1.2
```

else if patient_count = 3 multiply previously 2 No_Show with current No_show and divide with threshold

```
Example for B_ID = 8, Patient_count = 3, cut_off = (0.4*0.9*0.8)/0.2 = 1.44
```

And so on

The Expected Output:

```
B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num   Patient_count Cut_off_0.2   Cut_off_0.4
    1     0.2       S1        1          1             1             0.5
    2     0.3       S1        2          1             1.5           0.75
    3     0.8       S1        3          1             4              2
    4     0.3       S1        3          2             1.2            0.6
    5     0.6       S1        4          1             3              1.5
    6     0.8       S1        5          1             4              2
    7     0.9       S1        5          2             3.6            1.8
    8     0.4       S1        5          3             1.44           0.72
    9     0.6       S1        5          4             0.864          0.432
    12    0.9       S2        1          1             4.5            2.25
    13    0.5       S2        1          2             2.25           1.125
    14    0.3       S2        2          1             1.5            0.75
    15    0.7       S2        3          1             3.5            1.75
    20    0.7       S2        4          1             3.5            1.75
    16    0.6       S2        5          1             3              1.5
    17    0.8       S2        5          2             2.4            1.2
    19    0.3       S2        5          3             0.72           0.36
```

I tried below code

```
p = [0.2, 0.4]
for i in p:
    df['Cut_off_'+'i'] = df.groupby(['Session','slot_num'])['No_Show'].cumprod().div(i)
```

Comment: `'Cut_off' + str(i)` or f-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is possible here with `f-string`s with `{i}` for new columns names:

```
p = [0.2, 0.4]
for i in p:
    df[f'Cut_off_{i}'] = df.groupby(['Session','slot_num'])['No_Show'].cumprod().div(i)
```

Solution with numpy is also possible - output is converted to numpy array and divided by `p`, then converted to `DataFrame` and joined to original.

```
p = [0.2, 0.4]
arr = df.groupby(['Session','slot_num'])['No_Show'].cumprod().values[:, None] / np.array(p)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=p, index=df.index).add_prefix('Cut_off_'))
```

Comment: @jezreal which one will be faster numpy or pandas.. in terms of execution time

Comment: @ALI - I think best test in real data. But if p list has 1000 values and df has more like 10k rows I prefer second.

Comment: But if `p` only few values I think first solution is nicer ;)